# copy data from 2 table to 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

1. `VoiceZone1` : It contains 4 columns(Uname, TID, Res_Msg, Req_Time)
2. `VoiceZone2` : It also contains ( Uname, TID, Res_Msg, Req_Time)

Having another table `VoiceZoneLog`.

Want to copy all columns of `VoiceZone1` to `VoiceZoneLog` and two columns `Res_Msg`, `Req_Time` of `VoiceZone2` to `VoiceZoneLog` table.

Please Guide me using sql/mysql.

Give a Look to my query:

```
INSERT INTO VoiceZoneLog 
   SELECT A.REQ_TIME,
          B.RES_TIME,
          A.USER_NAME,
          A.TID,
          A.REQ_MSG,
          B.RES_MSG 
     FROM VoiceZone1 A, 
          VoiceZone2 B 
    WHERE A.TID=B.TID AND 
          A.REQ_MSG='CALL_LOGS_HISTORY 14'
```

So it executed properly but my task is want to optimize it.
I want any other way. So Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is fine, although it would be better written using standard join syntax and listing the columns for the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO VOICEZONE_LOGS (REQ_TIME, RES_TIME, USER_NAME, TID, REQ_MSG_A, REQ_MSG_B)
  SELECT A.REQ_TIME, B.RES_TIME, A.USER_NAME, A.TID, A.REQ_MSG, B.RES_MSG 
  FROM VZ_LOGS_REQ A join
       VZ_LOGS_RESP B
       ON A.TID = B.TID
  WHERE A.REQ_MSG='CALL_LOGS_HISTORY 14';
```

(The column names might be wrong in the insert, I just guessed.)

You can improve performance by having indexes.  I would recommend:  `vz_logs_req(req_msg, tid)` and vs_logs_resp(tid)`.